# Create series of heatmaps for each year in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, batch, heat-map, iteration

I'm working with QGIS 3.22.10-Białowieża and I've got a point layer with the attribute `year`. I need to create a series of heatmaps, one for each year, but I haven't found any filtering option in the `heatmapkerneldensity` tool (or any other) to perform such an iteration.

Is there an automatic way of doing so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can automate the task:

1. Create a model for your workflow ([find the model I created for this task here to download](https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/I5Cbl4OJyizM2aN))
2. Run your model in [batch mode](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing/batch.html), running it once for each year you wish.

### Create model

Create a model I linked above with 2 inputs: point layer and numer for year to be selected. Then add `Extract by expression` algorithm. For expression, choose `year = @year_selected` (change this to attribute name and model input name you have):

[image]

### Run model in batch mode

Run your model and choose batch mode. For year selected, use `Autofill...` and select `add values by expression`. Create an array that contains all years for which you want to generate a heatmap. For years 2015 to 2022, I used: `generate_series(2015,2022)`.

For input point layer and heatmap (output), fill in the first row and than choose `Fill down`. When you do this for the output, you will be promted for autofill mode: select `Fill with parameter values` and select `year_selected` to get the year added to the file name:

[image]

[image]

Comment: But, it would imply selecting each year one by one, doesn't it?

Comment: See changed answer

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use pyqgis.

It will extract each year by expression and execute kernel on the extracted points:

```py
#Adjust these five lines:
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('raapoint')[0] #Change name
datefield = 'sen_publi' #Same
output_folder = r'/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/' #Change
radius = 100000
pixel_size = 10000

values = list(layer.uniqueValues(layer.fields().indexOf(datefield))) #Find all values in datefield
years = list(set([x.year() for x in values])) #Extract unique years
print(f"years to process: {years}")

for year in years:
    print(year)
    subset = processing.run("native:extractbyexpression", 
        {'INPUT':layer,'EXPRESSION':f' year({datefield})={year}','OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})['OUTPUT']
    output = os.path.join(output_folder, f"kernel_{year}.tif")
    processing.run("qgis:heatmapkerneldensityestimation", {'INPUT':subset,
        'RADIUS':radius,'RADIUS_FIELD':'','PIXEL_SIZE':pixel_size,'WEIGHT_FIELD':'',
        'KERNEL':0,'DECAY':0,'OUTPUT_VALUE':0,'OUTPUT':output})
    
print('Done')
```

[image]