# Iterate shapefiles in a folder

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I'm trying to create wedge buffers for all splited points using the following model ( graphical modeler QGIS).[image]

The splited points are stored as shapefiles in a specific folder that I have created.

[image]

The problem is when I try to create wedge buffers for these points (using geometry by expression algorithm) It creates a wedge buffer for only one point.

[image]

Now when I try to use a "for loop" in the code of the model to iterate the shapefiles in the folder it displays an error saying "Could not load source layer for INPUT : C not found"
[image]

Comment: Wouldnt it be easier to use the [Wedge buffer](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgiswedgebuffers) processing tool then split the output layer?

Comment: Run the model in batch mode, see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/439840/88814